# Match text position on background

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a picture for my android app background and a text, I want to set my text in a specific point of the picture with RelativeLayout but the problem is in different cellphones with different resolution, size of both text and picture changed and the place of text is no longer the specific position, What can I do?

Comment: It is because of the different densities and screen sizes of the devices...
Can you post what have you tried?
To make the scene clear.

Comment: I tried dp for text position so that when the picture strached the text position strached too, but it is not where i put it ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Code block which is based on assumption that the font size is 30,and its position starts from center(50%left,50%top),

```
TextView t=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txt);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp=(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) t.getLayoutParams();
    Display D;
    D=getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
    float multiplier=(float)((float)dm.densityDpi/(160));
    lp.leftMargin=(int)(D.getWidth()*.5);
    lp.topMargin=(int)(D.getWidth()*.5);
    t.setTextSize(30*multiplier);
    t.setLayoutParams(lp);
```

multiplier will be 1 for 160dpi device and will change according other device densities,
Text position will always start from center of the screen..

Comment: I have a shape in 10% top of the picture, this is my point, in defualt device it is right but in other devices even with your code it is not exactly that point

Answer (score 0):

You can use percentage when calculating the position, when the image is resized the position of the point relative to its height/width should be the same.